# Find frequency of elements above a threshold for each cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, distribution, frequency

I have a 4-D matrix. The dimensions are longitude, latitude, days, years as [17,14,122,16].
I have to find out frequency of values above 98 percentile for each cell so that final output comes as as array of 17x14 containing number of occurrence of values above a 98 percent threshold.

I did something which gives me a matrix 17x14 of values associated with 98 percentile for each cell but I am unable to determine the frequency of occurrences.

```
k=0;
p=cell(1,238);
r=cell(1,238);

for i=1:17
   for j=1:14
      n=m(i,j,[1:122],[1:16]);
      n=squeeze(n);
      k=k+1;
      q=prctile(n(:),98);
      r{k}=nansum(nansum(n>=q));
      p{k}=q;
   end
end
```

This code gives matrix `p` fine but matrix `r` contains same values for all cells. How can this be possible?  What am I doing wrong with this?  Please help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch to 2D matrix since all your data is numberic?

Then the first column is longitude, second one is latitude and so on. Operations on this matrix will be easier to understand. Could you provide a minimal code example that will return an example of your 4D array?

Comment: After you do n=squeeze(n), it gives 2-D matrix of 122x16 dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the frequency of values above the 98th percentile is 2%.

I'm guessing the same value you are getting for `r` is 39; the number of elements in the top 2% of your 122x16 matrix (i.e. 1952 elements).

```
r = 0.02*1952; 

r = 
      39.040
```

Your code is verifying the theoretical value.  Perhaps you are thinking of a different question?

Here's a simulated example, using randomly generated (uniform distribution) from 0 to 100 for your data (`n`).

```
p=cell(1,238);
r=cell(1,238);
for i=1:17
    for j=1:14
        %         n=m(i,j,[1:122],[1:16]);
        %         n=squeeze(n);

        % After you do n=squeeze(n), it gives 2-D matrix of 122x16
        % dimensions.
        n = rand(122,16)*100;  % simulation for your 2-D matrix
        k=k+1;
        q=prctile(n(:),98);
        r{k}=nansum(nansum(n>=q));
        p{k}=q;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a long time ago. I think I should have improved the question. My statistics have improved since then.

Comment: Your welcome.  It was a while ago, but still a good question.  I wanted to answer it because I have done the same thing myself, on more than one occasion :)